# List of valid Vendor ID in Vendor ID payload

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I have some logs from a VPN with lines like this one:

```
Ignoring Vendor ID payload [4a131c8107035845...]
```

Can I use the hexadecimal code there to identify what kind of hardware attempted to establish a VPN with my hardware? If so, where can I found the list of possible Vendor ID (I cannot find one using google...).